# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace using Spring Batch and Wso2

Tags: java, spring, wso2, spring-batch

We are getting the below error when we are trying to integrate **Wso2 4.8.1** with **Spring batch 3.0.3** using spring mediator. The spring batch jar used has the xsd referred in the XML file. Both the mediator class jar and the spring batch jar are in the path `wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\components\lib`.

**Error**

> 2016-02-17 11:26:35,166 [-] [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR SynapseConfiguration Error in initializing Proxy Service [ SampleProxy1] Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
>   Offending resource: resource loaded through InputStream
>
> 2016-02-17 11:27:09,430 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-1] ERROR NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
>   Offending resource: resource loaded through InputStream

at

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.spring.SpringMediator.buildAppContext(SpringMediator.java:132)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.spring.SpringMediator.mediate(SpringMediator.java:81)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)

and

> 2016-02-17 11:28:10,272 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1] WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1
>   2016-02-17 11:39:25,506 [-] [Start Level Event Dispatcher] WARN ValidationResultPrinter

The default keystore (`wso2carbon.jks`) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC  "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
```